# Adding a line break after every 12 numbers inside a for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

My current code is:

```
for (count = 1; count <= 100; count = count + 1) {
  text = "<br>" + " " + count;
  document.getElementById("id").innerHTML += text;
}
```

When displaying it I need to add a line break after every 12 numbers in a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (count = 1; count <= 100; count = count + 1) {
  text = "<br>" + " " + count;
  if (count % 12 === 0) {
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML += text;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the [reminder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) and check if the result is zero.

Some annotations:

- declare all variables,
- collect all text,
- assign to element at the end.

```js
var text = "";
for (let count = 1; count <= 100; count++) {
    text += count + ' ';
    if (count % 12 === 0) {
        text += "<br>";
    }
}

document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML += text;
```

```html
<div id="demo5"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can help yourself with the `%` (remainder) operator. If `number % 12 === 0` is because that `number` is a multiple of `12`. You can use this to your advantage like so

```js
var text = "";
for (let count = 1; count <= 100; count++) {
    text += count + ' ';
    if (count % 12 === 0) {
        text += "<br>";
    }
}

document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += text;
```

```html
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Another way could be to explicitly count how many items you're currently having and reset that count whenever it reaches `12`:

```js
    var text = "";
    var n = 0;
    for (let count = 1; count <= 100; count++) {
        text += count + ' ';
        n++;
        if (n === 12) {
            n = 0;
            text += "<br>";
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += text;
```

```html
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

```js
for (count = 1; count <= 100; count = count + 1) {
  text += count+ " ";
  if(count%12 == 0){
     text = text + "</br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = text;
}
```